# React native stack, drawer, tab, stack navigation order

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

This is the code which I am using for Main navigator.

```
export const MainNavigations = StackNavigator({
    Auth: {
        screen: AuthNavigation
    },
    Main: {
        screen: DrawerNavigations
    }
}, {
        initialRouteName: 'Auth',
        headerMode: 'none'
    });
```

No issue with AuthNavigation.

This is my Drawer Navigator

```
const DrawerRoutes = {
    AppHome: {
        screen: TabNavigations,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: 'Home',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon size={20} color="#bdc3c7" name="home" />
        }
    },
    UserSettings: {
        screen: UserSettingsStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: 'Preferences',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon size={20} color="#bdc3c7" name="gear" />
        }
    },
    Logout: {
        screen: Logout,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: 'Logout',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon size={20} color="#bdc3c7" name="sign-out" />
        }
    }
};

export const DrawerNavigations = DrawerNavigator(DrawerRoutes, {
    initalRouteName: 'AppHome',
    contentComponent: (props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />,
    mode: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'modal' : 'card'
});
```

This is my Tab Navigator

```
export const TabNavigations = TabNavigator({
    HomeTab: {
        screen: HomeStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        }
    },
    CirclesTab: {
        screen: CirclesStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: "Circles"
        }
    }
}, {
        initialRouteName: "HomeTab",
        swipeEnabled: false,
        animationEnabled: true,
        tabBarComponent: NavigationComponent,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        tabBarOptions: {
            bottomNavigationOptions: {
                style: {
                    borderTopWidth: 0.2,
                    borderTopColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
                },
                backgroundColor: '#FFF',
                activeLabelColor: '#3498db',
                tabs: {
                    HomeTab: {
                        icon: <Icon size={24} color="#bdc3c7" name="home" />,
                        activeIcon: <Icon size={24} color="#3498db" name="home" />
                    },
                    CirclesTab: {
                        icon: <Icon size={24} color="#bdc3c7" name="circle-o" />,
                        activeIcon: <Icon size={24} color="#3498db" name="circle-o" />
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This issue is, when I navigate to Main navigator, the Tab is auto swiped to CirclesStack screen.
Please help, if you get my point.

This is how I am performing navigation:

```
const firstAction = NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    key: null,
    actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: 'Main'
        }),
    ],
});

const initialNavState = MainNavigations.router.getStateForAction(firstAction);
```

Here it is my Circle Stack:

```
const CirclesStack = StackNavigator({
    Circles: {
        screen: Circles,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: 'Circles',
            headerLeft: <DrawerIcon navigate={navigation.navigate} />,
            headerTintColor: colors.primaryBackground,
            headerTitleStyle: defaultStyles.tabText,
            headerStyle: defaultStyles.tabContainer
        })
    },
    AddCircle: {
        screen: AddCircle,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Add Circle',
            headerTintColor: colors.primaryBackground,
            headerTitleStyle: defaultStyles.tabText,
            headerStyle: defaultStyles.tabContainer
        }
    },
    SingleCircle: {
        screen: SingleCircle,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTintColor: colors.primaryBackground,
            headerTitleStyle: defaultStyles.tabText,
            headerStyle: defaultStyles.tabContainer
        }
    },
    EditCircle: {
        screen: EditCircle,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Edit Circle',
            headerTintColor: colors.primaryBackground,
            headerTitleStyle: defaultStyles.tabText,
            headerStyle: defaultStyles.tabContainer
        }
    },
    SingleEvent: {
        screen: SingleEvent,
        path: 'event/:id',
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTintColor: colors.primaryBackground,
            headerTitleStyle: defaultStyles.tabText,
            headerStyle: defaultStyles.tabContainer
        }
    },
    AddEvent: {
        screen: AddEvent,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Add Event',
            headerTintColor: colors.primaryBackground,
            headerTitleStyle: defaultStyles.tabText,
            headerStyle: defaultStyles.tabContainer
        }
    },
    EditEvent: {
        screen: EditEvent,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Edit Event',
            headerTintColor: colors.primaryBackground,
            headerTitleStyle: defaultStyles.tabText,
            headerStyle: defaultStyles.tabContainer
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you paste a snippet of what your `HomeStack` navigator looks like as well? There might be something there that's causing this unintended action you're describing.

Comment: Here it is:

 const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
   screen: Home,
   navigationOptions: {
    title: 'Home'
   }
  }
 }, {
   initialRouteName: "Home",
   headerMode: "none"
  });

Comment: Okay, and what is inside your `Home` component?

Comment: Home screen is just fetching the data from server, no navigation to any of the circle screen from Home screen.
But when I change Circle Stack to any other screen that works, and doesn't swipes.
Seems like the issue is with Circle Stack configuration.
See my Circle Stack code in question, I have added now.